# Error occured when launching bundle Main keter

Tags: haskell, yesod, keter

I've done everything on my yesod project but the keter gives me an error log message like this:

```
  Unpacking bundle '/opt/keter/incoming/Main.keter'
  Error occured when launching bundle Main: Codec.Compression.Zlib: incorrect header check
```

i also post an issue on [keter github](https://github.com/snoyberg/keter/issues/85) maybe some also help me.

thank you in advance.

Comment: Sounds like it's an invalid archive. Could you provide more information? If you use the `yesod keter` command it should create a valid archive for you.

Comment: i already solve it there is some error on my keter.yaml file. so it was giving me error like this. thank you